# Как правильно декодировать изображение отправленное через WebSocket

Tags: python, node.js, изображения, typescript

Как правильно декодировать строку, чтобы из нее получить изображение. На стороне клиента данные кодируются таким образом

```py
def finger_detection(self):
    image = GetFingerprint()
    print(image)
    print("Finger detected")
    width, height = image.size    
    #image = np.asarray(image);
    print("Send finger")
    byteIO=io.BytesIO()
    image.save(byteIO,format="PNG")
    imageBuffer=byteIO.getvalue()
    encodeBuffer=base64.b64encode(imageBuffer)
    resp_data={
        'action' : ResponseActions.RESULT_IMAGE_ACTION,
        'payload' : str(encodeBuffer)
    }
    self.socket.send(json.dumps(resp_data))
    print("---")
```

Код на стороне сервера

```js
private onMessage(ev:globalThis.MessageEvent):any{
    const incomingMessage:ClientEvent=JSON.parse(ev.data);
    console.log(incomingMessage);
    let buffer=new Buffer(incomingMessage.payload,"utf8");
    fs.writeFile(filePath+genHexString()+".png",buffer,{encoding:"base64"},(err:NodeJS.ErrnoException|null)=>{
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: В коде python замените `str(encodeBuffer)` на `encodeBuffer.decode()`.
Метод `base64.b64encode()` возвращает набор байт, а применение str к набору байт портит вам данные: из набора байт вида `b'SGVsbG8='` у вас получится строка `"b'SGVsbG8='"`, а для того чтобы сервер смог декодировать данные, вам нужна строка `'SGVsbG8='`. Чтобы решить проблему, нужно просто декодировать байты кодировкой по умолчанию вместо приведения к строке: `encodeBuffer.decode()`. Не ответом, потому что не уверен в правильности js части.

Comment: @insolor твое решение на Python помогло. Спасибо большое) Я просто не знал, что str() добавляет первый символ кодировки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил на клиенте, спасибо @insolor. На стороне сервера сделал таким образом.

```
private onMessage(ev:globalThis.MessageEvent):any{
    const incomingMessage:ClientEvent=JSON.parse(ev.data);
    console.log(incomingMessage);
    let imageBuffer:Buffer=new Buffer(incomingMessage.payload,"base64");
    fs.writeFile(filePath+genHexString()+".png",imageBuffer,{encoding:null},(err:NodeJS.ErrnoException|null)=>{
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
    });
```